# objective c nspredicates with OR's unable to parse

Tags: objective-c, ios, nspredicate

Anyone know why this gives an "Unable to parse the format string" error at runtime?

```
[wordListArray filterUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"pinyin contains[cd] %@ OR pinyin contains[cd] %@ OR BEGINSWITH[cd] %@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@1", searchTerm], [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@2", searchTerm], searchTerm]];
```

for some reason i get this when ever i do complex predicates (ie those with OR's on them). i thought nspredicate is supposed to be able to hand this?

Comment: How about this `@"(pinyin contains[cd] %@) OR (pinyin contains[cd] %@) OR (BEGINSWITH[cd] %@)"`? Any change? Also before `BEGINSWITH[cd] %@` are you missing something?

Comment: thats it! I've been staring at this for days and re-writing these queries over and over and haven't been able to get it to work until your comment - sometimes the brain doesn't see things.. thank you!

Comment: Sometimes all you need is an extra pair of eyes to look into that. :) Glad to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing some search key word or so before `"BEGINSWITH[cd] %@"`. Add it and check if it is still showing this error. Probably you are looking into something like,

`@"(pinyin contains[cd] %@) OR (pinyin contains[cd] %@) OR (pinyin BEGINSWITH[cd] %@)"`

Comment: Yes! i was missing the thing before the begins with.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, `AND` and `OR` didn't work for me either, but `&&` and `||` did.

Comment: I remember there was a flag i needed to set somewhere to enable the "AND" and "OR" format. I cant find it anymore in the docs in my usual goto places. maybe someone else reading this might be able to fill us in.